# Как создать php скрипт для вывода html страниц?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Как создать php скрипт для вывода html страниц?
Решил создать "новостную ленту".
С html,css всё прописано.
Этот блок отвечает за список новостей. Он находитсья на странице "/news/".

```
<article class="news">
          <h2 class="pageTitle"><span class="frame_bg"><span></span></span></h2>
          <div class="listArea">
                        <ul class="list">
                            <li id="1">
                <div class="inner">
                  <div class="dateArea">
                    <p class="year"></p>
                    <p class="month"></p>

                  </div>
                  <div class="ttlArea"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="./?article_id=2"></a>
              </li>
                            <li id="2">
                <div class="inner">
                  <div class="dateArea">
                    <p class="year"></p>
                    <p class="month"></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ttlArea"></div>
                </div>
                <a href="./?article_id=2"></a>
              </li>
             </ul>
          </div>
                  </article>
```

Скрипт должен выводить полный код html страниц по "li id="(Номер Новости)""

на страницы с адресом вида "/news/?article_id=(Номер Новости)" 
Пример части кода для вывода :

```
    <article class="news">
      <h2 class="pageTitle"><span class="frame_bg"><span>NEWS</span></span></h2>
      <div class="detailArea">
        <div class="newsTitle">
          <div class="dateArea">
            <p class="year"></p>
            <p class="month"></p>
          </div>
          <div class="ttlArea">Some Text</div>
        </div>
        <div class="detailTxtArea">
            Some Text
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btnBack">
        <span>BACK</span>
        <a href="/news/"></a>
      </div>
    </article>
```

Данные для подстановки будут храниться в 
файлах.

Comment: Необходимый текст и другая информация о странице хранится в базе данных?

Comment: Пока что начните с простого - шаблонизатор вам как раз сейчас в помощь будет https://webformyself.com/mustache-shablonizator-bez-logiki/          подскажите где будут храниться данные для подстановки в html - в файле, в базе данных, на другом сервере?

Comment: Спасибо. Но шаблонизатор не подходит